# Drupal: getting user information

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, profile

How can I get information about the loged in user when I load a random website page ?

I need to grab a profile field to customize the page look

thanks

Comment: Are you writing a custom module, or are you attempting to use the front-end? Please give more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current user information is always available as a global, so you just do:

```
global $user;
// $user will now be a stdClass object representing the current user, logged in or not
// If you are only interested in logged in users, a standard check would be
if (0 != $user->uid) {
  // Do something for/with logged in users
}
```

The anonymous user will have uid 0, the admin (first) user will have 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of a bunch of variables you can use: http://web.rhizom.nl/development/drupal-variables-in-theme-files/.

This page shows how to grab variables such as the users email address: http://11heavens.com/Drupal-coder-lost-in-space/who-is-she.

Answer (score 1):

Erics' answer works for Themes. The standard way in modules is to do `global $user` to get the logged in user. I personally don't like using globals in this way but when in rome...

Answer (score 0):

Profile values are always loaded in any user object obtained with the function `user_load()`. The global variable `$user` contains the information for the currently logged in user. If you are looking for the value of the profile named `profile_realname`, you can use the following code:

```
global $user:

// Avoid the anonymous user, which doesn't have any profile field.
if ($user->uid) {
  $realname = $user->profile_realname;
}
```